# SignedCms.ComputeSignature throws "The object identifier is poorly formatted"

Tags: c#, cryptography, pkcs#7

This exception starts to be thrown recently, the code was working fine:

```
public byte[] Sign(CmsMessage cmsMessage, CspKeyInfo keyInfo)
{
    ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(new Oid(cmsMessage.ContentTypeOid), cmsMessage.Content);

    var cspObj = new CspParameters()
    {
        ProviderName = keyInfo.ProviderName,
        ProviderType = keyInfo.ProviderType,
        KeyNumber = (int)KeyNumber.Signature,
        Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey,
        KeyContainerName = keyInfo.ContainerName
    };
    var signer = new CmsSigner(cspObj)
    {
        DigestAlgorithm = new Oid(cmsMessage.SignerHashAlgorithmOid)
    };

    signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime());

    var signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, cmsMessage.Detached);
    signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
    var encodeByteBlock = (ByteBlock)signedCms.Encode();
    return encodeByteBlock;
}
```

The `signer`'s `SignerIdentifierType` is `SubjectKeyIdentifier`
but it throws: `CryptographicException` at `ComputeSignature`

> The object identifier is poorly formatted

The dummy certificate has a private key (`HasPrivateKey` is `true`)